# R code summing one column if other column are equal

Tags: r

So I have a data set of two columns, one being dates in year-month-day form and another column being numbers. If certain dates are equal to each other, I want to add the respective other column numbers. My data file is called df and it has a Date column and Weekly_Sales column.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

First, it is usually a good idea to convert dates as strings to a date type with as.Date(), but not really necessary in this case.

The usual way to do what you are asking is to use the aggregate() function, which will apply a function such as sum() to groups of values grouped by the argument by=date.